# Running custom NPM commands in parallel and timing

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm wanting to use Google Lighthouse NPM package however unlike all their examples which run against a public URL, I'm wanting to use it on my localhost.

Question is, I need to run the NPM scripts in the following order which is what I'm struggling with:

1. Run my dev server script (runs create-react-app dev server and runs localhost:3000)
2. Wait until server is up and running
3. Keep dev server running and run the Google Lighthouse NPM script against localhost:3000
4. Once Google Lighthouse has finished doing it's audits then kill the dev server.

All a question of either manual timings or if something can use a callback. Also need to consider two tasks running at the same time.